# Unable to create apple map address link with latitude and longitude in swift

Tags: swift, apple-maps

I am trying to create apple map address link with latitude and longitude

**i have tried like this:**

```
  let addrLoction = addressModel[indexPath.row]

                   let coord = addrLo.location
                   latitude = coord?.latitude
                   longitude = coord?.longitude

    
   let mapAddr =  "http://maps.apple.com/?q={latitude},{longitude}"
```

**getting error:**

> Expected expression after operator

**for eg**: like android app goole maps address link, i need in apple map address link

[image]

Comment: In which lines do you get the error?

Comment: @sp4c38 here  `let mapAddr =  "http://maps.apple.com/?q={latitude},{longitude}" 
`

Comment: Does changing the last line to `let mapAddr = "http://maps.apple.com/?q=\(latitude),\(longitude)"` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. `latitude` and `longitude` are optionals. Even if the String Interpolation syntax was right you'll get something like `"Optional(45.000)"`. Use Optional Bindings.
2. The String Interpolation syntax is wrong, it's `\(value)`

   ```
   if let coord = addrLo.location {
       let latitude = coord.latitude
       let longitude = coord.longitude

       let mapAddr = "https://maps.apple.com/?q=\(latitude),\(longitude)" 
       // ...
   }
   ```

And the URL scheme should be `https`